# Spaces in filenames causing problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, whitespace

```
FileInfo[] FileList1 = Dir.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList1)
{
    Response.Write(
        "<td><a href= view5.aspx?file=" + strheadlinesid + "\\" + 
        FI.Name + " target=_self;> " +FI.Name + "</a></td>");
}
```

When I tried to print file names with spaces it's adding '#' in the place of space in file name which creating problems for me.
Can anybody tell solution to

Answer (score 5):

URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string.

```
fileName = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(fileName);
```

Comment: Only this would happen automatically in this case, as the browser would URLEncode the link automatically.  User forgot to add quotation marks.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please.I couldn't understand.

Comment: If you know your sending text that might contain special characters always UrlEncode it.

Comment: FI = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(FI); I added this line but it's giving error.

Answer (score 2):

**Try using Quotation Marks!**

```
FileInfo[] FileList1 = Dir.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList1)
{
    Response.Write(
        "<td><a href=\"view5.aspx?file=" + strheadlinesid + "\\" + 
        FI.Name + "\" target=\"_self\"> " +FI.Name + "</a></td>");
}
```